# Spring Cloud Gateway Getting a 500 Exception while trying to refresh_token using expired access_token and refresh_token

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway, refresh-token

I have a secured Spring Cloud Gateway application using `ServerHttpSecurity.oauth2Login()` that can successfully renew expired access tokens using the `refresh token`. However, **when the refresh token also expires and the application tries to renew the access token with it, I get a 500 Internal Server Error**  [seems to be caused by a 400 Bad Request error just before it] with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientAuthorizationException: [invalid_grant] Token is not active
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.RefreshTokenReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.lambda$authorize$0(RefreshTokenReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:97) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
```

Full logs here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/files/8319348/logs.txt

Only if I re-issue the request (refresh browser with the call to the secured endpoint), I will get redirected to the login page **(desired behavior).**

While debugging, I noticed that re-issuing the request after the 500 Internal Server Error under the hood results in the following exception:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientAuthorizationRequiredException: [client_authorization_required] Authorization required for Client Registration Id: <client-id>.
```

and that is probably what causes the redirect to the login page.

[Request execution details here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1t0X.png)

My question: Can I avoid getting the 500 Internal Server Error and instead be redirected to the login page? If yes, how can I accomplish that?

**Environment details**
Spring Boot: 2.4.0
Spring Cloud: 2020.0.0
Spring Security: 5.4.1

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find a solution? Thanks

Comment: Hi @diego.gazzola , added an answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to catch the 500 caused while refreshing a token and then initiating a new authorization flow, using the next classes:

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.*;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

/**
 * A delegating implementation of ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager to help deal with a 500 Internal Server Error
 * that is a result of an expired access token. With ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManagerCustom, we manage to redirect
 * to the login page instead of returning a 500 Internal Server Error to the user/client.
 */
public class ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManagerCustom implements ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager {

    private final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;
    private final ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository;
    private final ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager;

    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManagerCustom(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                       ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
        this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
        this.authorizedClientRepository = authorizedClientRepository;
        this.authorizedClientManager = new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                this.clientRegistrationRepository, this.authorizedClientRepository
        );
    }

    public Mono<OAuth2AuthorizedClient> authorize(OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest) {
        Assert.notNull(authorizeRequest.getClientRegistrationId(), "Client registration id cannot be null");

        return this.authorizedClientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest)
                // The token has expired, therefore we initiate a new grant flow
                .onErrorMap(
                        ClientAuthorizationException.class,
                        error -> new ClientAuthorizationRequiredException(authorizeRequest.getClientRegistrationId())
                );
    }
}
```

And then adding the next @Bean

```
 public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManagerCustomConfig(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                             ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
        this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
        this.authorizedClientRepository = authorizedClientRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager() {
        return new ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManagerCustom(
                this.clientRegistrationRepository, this.authorizedClientRepository
        );
    }
```